# Forking and exiting from child in python

Tags: python, fork, system, exit

I'm trying to fork a process, do something in the child and then exit from it (see code below). To exit I first tried sys.exit which turned out to be a problem because an intermediate function caught the SystemExit exception (as in the code below) and so the child didn't actually terminate. I figured out that I should use os._exit instead. Now the child terminates, but I still see defunct processes lying around (when I do `ps -ef`). Is there a way to avoid these?

```
import os, sys

def fctn():
    if os.fork() != 0:
        return 0
#   sys.exit(0)
    os._exit(0)

while True:
    str = raw_input()
    try:
        print(fctn())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Caught SystemExit.')
```

**Edit**: this was actually not really a Python question but more of a Unix question (so I guess results may vary depending on the system). Ivan's answer suggests that I should do something like

```
def handleSIGCHLD(sig, frame):
    os.wait()

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, handleSIGCHLD)
```

while for me a simple

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

also works.

And then it's probably true that I should use some library...

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to catch `SystemExit` in the first place; I'd recommend not doing so unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Actually, I'm not catching it myself. I'm implementing do_POST in BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler and some function that calls it catches the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You should `wait()` for a child to remove its zombie process entry from the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Finally, to offload tasks to children, you may be better off with [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 0):

you are better off using the subprocess module for your need. Its the preferred way of forking off a process.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

Comment: OP is not calling `os.exec*()`, so the entire `subprocess` module is inappropriate for this use-case (i.e. they are not executing some external binary, so there is nothing to pass to `subprocess.call()` and friends).

Comment: Right i misunderstood "fork a process and do something with the child" in this context. Voting up the other answer